# Submission failed - 5.7 Apps and add-ins must be secured with a valid and trusted SSL certificate (HTTPS)

Tags: office365, excel-addins, office365-apps, office-js

I submitted an App in the Office365 Store but it got rejected. The requirement to fix is 5.7 Apps and add-ins must be secured with a valid and trusted SSL certificate (HTTPS). Your add-in and all its content must be SSL secured.

[image: problem]

Any information regarding how to fix this will be really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you've included non-SSL resources in your add-in.

One way to identify the problem(s) is to search all your code (html and JS, of course) for occurrences of "http". Make sure that every one of them is using "https" and not "http".

-Michael (program manager on the add-ins team)

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the app was consuming the non-SSL bit.ly API. Now I have changed the code to use https://api-ssl.bitly.com. The only problem I'm facing now is that when I try to debug the app, it is still using the "old version". I thought a Clean/Build would be enough, but it doesn't work. I'll check that, but my original question has already been answered thanks to you :)

Comment: Clearing your browser cache or setting it to never read from cache during development can help with this issue.